# Set Values In Array equal to 1 or 0 only

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I'm a beginner in C trying to ask the user to enter how many numbers in an array they want (up to 10) and then to enter those values. However my project says I have to set the values in the array to 1 (if there is a value) or 0 (if there isn't one). What I also don't understand is I'm supposed to find the difference and compliment of the arrays, but wouldn't changing the values change the answer too?

ex: if the user enters 2 4 5 then the array would look like (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).

This is what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
    int o = 0;
    int p = 0;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter the number of elements for set A: ");
    scanf("%d",&o);

    int c[o];

    printf("\nEnter the numbers in set A:\n");
    for(i=0;i<o;i++) {
        scanf("%d",&c[i]);
    }

    printf("\nEnter the number of elements for set B: ");
    scanf("%d",&p);

    int d [p];

    printf("\nEnter the numbers in set B:\n");
    for(i=0;i<p;i++) {
        scanf("%d",&d[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code?

Comment: I'm unsure of how to set those values that the user enters to 1 within the array.

Comment: maybe You need `bool setA[10] = {false}, setB[10] = {false};`

Comment: If you have two sets, A and B, surely it would be sensible to use the names `a` and `b` for the arrays holding them?  Also, you should use functions to avoid code duplication.

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/hlLBIV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your project means is that when user enters any number, you have to set the index of the array corresponding to that number to `1`.

For e.g. if user enters `1`, the your array should look like `(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`. As array index is `0` based you set the second element to `1` and not the first.

**EDIT: 1**

Your code should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int o = 0;
    int p = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int input = 0;

    printf("Enter the number of elements for set A: ");
    scanf("%d",&o);
    int c[10];//Edited to correct the size of Array as mentioned by @Jonathan Leffler in the comments
    //To set the initial values to 0
    for(i=0; i<o; i++)
    {
        c[i] = 0;
    }

    //Set the value at the index to 1 when user enters it, as you don't need to store them
    printf("\nEnter the numbers in set A:\n");
    for(i=0; i<o; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &input);
        c[input] = 1;
    }

    printf("\nEnter the number of elements for set B: ");
    scanf("%d",&p);
    int d[10];
    //To set the initial values to 0
    for(i=0; i<p; i++)
    {
        d[i] = 0;
    }

    printf("\nEnter the numbers in set B:\n");
    for(i=0; i<p; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &input);
        d[input] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I'm not changing the actual values, just the index?

Comment: No. You are changing the values in the array itself. You can't change the index. You have to change the values in that array at the specified index.

Comment: @DoctorCloud: you read an index value (e.g. 4) and then set `a[4] = 1`.  Except the value 4 is in a (simple, non-array) variable, not a literal.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So can I just say that if the value a[x] != 0 then a[x] = 1?

Comment: @DoctorCloud: you can test it, but it isn't necessary. Simply set it unless you want to raise a warning or error if the entry has already been set.

Comment: @VatsalSura Thanks for that. So it looks like I was missing a variable that stores that input, and then setting that input equal to 1?

Comment: Note that this code does not currently set the array sizes correctly.  You need to allow indexes 0..9, as shown in the "ex" line in the question, but you're limiting `c` to the number of entries the user will make.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for mentioning it. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to set 1 or zero `!!` will come to help

```
printf("\nEnter the numbers in set A:\n");
for(i=0;i<o;i++) {
    if(scanf("%d",&c[i]) == 1)
    {
        c[i] = !!c[i];
    }
    else
    {
    /* do something if scanf failed */
    }
}
```